# Working on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

Some Jews, who are otherwise very observant, work on Shabbat because their livelihood depends on it. This was more true in the days of massive immigration to the US than it is today, but I see it today also.

Have some halachic authorities ever issued leniencies on this subject?  I am not talking about saving lives, even though one can argue that it sometimes does, albeit indirectly.

Comment: How do you define "observant"? Have you asked these people how they reconcile their actions with Halacha?

Comment: Does their work involve melacha?

Comment: Do you mean leniences to allow such activity or to mitigate the halachic consequences after the fact?

Comment: One is supposed to spend all their money to avoid violating a "thou shalt not" commandment. Did questions come up about people who were already doing so, how to react? Yes, sure. Rabbi J David Bleich has an article called *May a Sabbath Desecrator Drink His Own Wine?"

Comment: @shmosel  Leniencies to allow, possibly on the grounds that you have to earn a living to survive.

Comment: @Shalom Do you know where I can find that article?

Comment: https://traditiononline.org/survey-of-recent-halkhic-periodical-literature-may-a-sabbath-desecrator-drink-wine/